# Simply connected spaces and loops as boundaries of surfaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

If I have a simply connected space $X$, given a closed loop $\gamma$ passing through two points $x_1,x_2\in X$ can I always find an orientable 2-surface in $X$ with boundary $\gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the equivalence relation which identifies $(t,0)$ and $(-t,0)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. The image in the quotient space of the circle of radius 2 is a counterexmaple.

Comment: What if $\gamma$ is a simple closed path??? In that case if I consider the boundary circle of Möbius strip in $\mathbb R^3$... Does this give a counter example???